# importing python nested modules with google colab file system

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have submodule in my project director with that struct

```
submodule/
         __init__.py
         nested/
               __init__.py
               aa.py
```

the `__init__.py` in `submodule/` contains the following code

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))

import aa
```

and the `__init__.py` in `submodule/nested` contains the following code

```
from .aa import *
```

so if I'm in a directory with `submodule` I can execute the following and everything would be fine

```
import submodules.aa
```

but it fails on google colab, I guess it is most probably because of this line don't do the supposed functionality

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))
```

I'm trying to do the above importing from jupyter notebook that I want to run on google colab

Answer (score 1):

That fixed the problem by writing the following in `submodule/__init__.py`

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))

try:
  import google.colab  # so I only do it when I'm on google colab
  sys.path.insert(0, "/content/submodule")
except:
  pass

import aa
```